# Doesn't working predicat of logical and (&&) in while

Tags: java, loops, while-loop

```
public void ReadPixels(String path, FormController form){
    Image image = new Image(path);
    PixelReader reader = image.getPixelReader();
    int x = 0;
    int y = 0;
    int stopX = 0;
    int stopY = 0;
    while(x != form.canvas.getWidth()-1 && y != form.canvas.getHeight()-1){
        while(x < stopX+20-1 && y < stopY+25-1){
            int argb = reader.getArgb(x, y);
            int r = (argb >> 24) & 0xFF;
            int g = (argb >>  8) & 0xFF;
            int b =  argb        & 0xFF;
            Pixels pixel = new Pixels(r,g,b);
            Pixels[][] array = new Pixels[20][25];
            Matrix matrix = new Matrix();
            array[x][y] = pixel;
            matrix.setArray(array);
            if(x != stopX+20-1){
                x++;
            }
            if(y != stopY+25-1){
                y++;
            }

        }
        x++;
        y++;
        stopX=x;
        stopY=y;
    }
}
```

I have a problem. In the while loop, when `x` increments to 19, the while goes out of its block. WHY??

In while situated logical AND &&. It means that loop will be over when the first and the second part of the expression will be FALSE

Comment: You should (always) add a tag with your programming language.

Answer (score 1):

> In while situated logical AND &&. It means that loop will be over when the first and the second part of the expression will be FALSE

No, you got it backwards. The loop will continue, *while* both conditions are *true*, i.e. it *stops*, when *any* of the conditions is violated.

In your case, then `x` is `19`, the condition `x < stopX+20-1` is `false` (with `stopX` being `0`), so the inner loop stops.

Try changing the condition to `while(x < stopX+20-1 || y < stopY+25-1){` if you want the loop to stop when both conditions are false.

Answer (score 0):

The first time through the inner loop, `stopX` is `0`, so you exit the inner loop when `x` (and `y`) are 19. Then you set `stopX=x` so `stopX` is now `19`.

So the second time through the inner loop, the condition on `x` is `x < 19 + 20 -1`, i.e. the loop will continue until `x = 38`. When `x` reaches `20` you get an `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException` accessing `array[x][y]`.